# Property does not exist on type 'Query'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I want to create a mongoose schema, and I am trying to add a new property named start to the document. It works in javascript, but in typescript, I am getting an error  "Property 'start' does not exist on type 'Query<any, any, {}, any>'.ts(2339)".

I appreciate any help you can provide to fix the error.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
interface tourSchemaTypes {
  name: string;
}

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema<tourSchemaTypes>({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
    unique: true,
  },
});

const Tour = mongoose.model<tourSchemaTypes>('Tour', tourSchema);

tourSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.find({ secretTour: { $ne: true } });
  this.start = Date.now(); 
  next();
});

tourSchema.post(/^find/, function (docs, next) {
  console.log(`Query took ${Date.now() - this.start} milliseconds`);
  console.log(docs);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in TypeScript because you can't simply extend `this` which is of type `Query<any, any, {}, any>` in the context of those functions with an arbitrary key named `start`.

Instead you could use something like a `WeakMap` to keep track of any additional information you'd want to have for each Query.

```js
const queryStartTsMap = new WeakMap<Query<any, any>, number>();

tourSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.find({ secretTour: { $ne: true } });
  queryStartTsMap.set(this, Date.now());
  next();
});

tourSchema.post(/^find/, function (docs, next) {
  const queryStartTs = queryStartTsMap.get(this);
  if (queryStartTs) {
    console.log(`Query took ${Date.now() - queryStartTs} milliseconds`);
    queryStartTsMap.delete(this);
  }
  console.log(docs);
  next();
});
```